# how to add this jquery script in to wordpress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress

i liked this countdown script from http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html and want to use this one to my wordpress website , i read some tutorials about how to put any script in wordpress but i could not understand exactly cause i am newbie , can you help me to do this step by step

**now i will show the script author instructions to use this script on normal html page 
i want to do these steps also but in wordpress .**

1. Include the necessary javascript files at the end of the page.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js">     
   </script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kinetic.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.final-countdown.js"></script>
   ```
2. Include the required bootstrap 3 CSS in the head of the page.

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet"          
    href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```
3. Create a countdown timer using the html structure like this:

   ```
   <div class="countdown-container container">
   <div class="clock row">

   <!-- days --> 
   <div class="clock-item clock-days countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="wrap">
   <div class="inner">
   <div id="canvas_days" class="clock-canvas"></div>
   <div class="text">
   <p class="val">0</p>
   <p class="type-days type-time">DAYS</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <!-- hours --> 

   <div class="clock-item clock-hours countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="wrap">
   <div class="inner">
   <div id="canvas_hours" class="clock-canvas"></div>
   <div class="text">
   <p class="val">0</p>
   <p class="type-hours type-time">HOURS</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <!-- minutes --> 
   <div class="clock-item clock-minutes countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="wrap">
   <div class="inner">
   <div id="canvas_minutes" class="clock-canvas"></div>
   <div class="text">
   <p class="val">0</p>
   <p class="type-minutes type-time">MINUTES</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   <!-- seconds --> 
   <div class="clock-item clock-seconds countdown-time-value col-sm-6 col-md-3">
   <div class="wrap">
   <div class="inner">
   <div id="canvas_seconds" class="clock-canvas"></div>
   <div class="text">
   <p class="val">0</p>
   <p class="type-seconds type-time">SECONDS</p>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>

   </div>
   ```

   4. Add the following CSS snippet to your CSS file.

      html, body {
        height: 100%;
         }
         html {
         background-image: url('../img/sample.jpg');
         background-position: center center;
         background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      }
      body {
      background-color: rgba(44,62,80 , 0.6 );
      background-image: url('../img/pattern.png');
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: repeat;
      font-family: 'Raleway', 'Arial', sans-serif;
      }
      .countdown-container {
      position: relative;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
      -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
       transform: translateY(-50%);
      }
      .clock-item .inner {
      height: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      }
      .clock-canvas {
      background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
      border-radius: 50%;
      height: 0px;
      padding-bottom: 100%;
      }
      .text {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
      margin-top: -50px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      text-align: center;
      text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
      width: 100%;
       }
       .text .val {
      font-size: 50px;
       }
      .text .type-time {
      font-size: 20px;
       }
      @media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
      .clock-item {
       margin-bottom: 30px;
       }
       }
       @media (max-width: 767px) {
       .clock-item {
       margin: 0px 30px 30px 30px;
       }
       }
4. Initialize the countdown timer and set the start time, end time and current time in the javascript.

   ```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
    start: '1362139200',
    end: '1388461320',
    now: '1387461319'
     });
    </script>
   ```
5. All the default options.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.countdown').final_countdown({
   start: '1362139200',
   end: '1388461320',
   now: '1387461319',
   selectors: {
   value_seconds: '.clock-seconds .val',
   canvas_seconds: 'canvas_seconds',
   value_minutes: '.clock-minutes .val',
   canvas_minutes: 'canvas_minutes',
   value_hours: '.clock-hours .val',
   canvas_hours: 'canvas_hours',
   value_days: '.clock-days .val',
   canvas_days: 'canvas_days'
     },
    seconds: {
      borderColor: '#7995D5',
      borderWidth: '6'
    },
     minutes: {
     borderColor: '#ACC742',
     borderWidth: '6'
    },
    hours: {
      borderColor: '#ECEFCB',
      borderWidth: '6'
     },
     days: {
     borderColor: '#FF9900',
     borderWidth: '6'
   }}, function() {
   // Finish callback
   });
   });
   ```

Comment: are you receiving an error?  or ?  it's not entirely clear what your problem is.

Comment: no i want to put this script and work in wordpress

Comment: what part are you having trouble with?  you've listed out the steps, but it's not clear what you problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add Javascript and CSS files inside Wordpress, you need to use [`wp_register_script`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [`wp_register_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style) functions inside your *functions.php* theme file.

So let's translate every step:

> Include the necessary javascript files at the end of the page.

You don't need to include jquery as it is already included by Wordpress. Download *kinetic.js* and *jquery.final-countdown.js*, and add them into your theme folder in a *js* directory.

Then in your functions.php add the following:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('kinetic', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/kinetic.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
    wp_enqueue_script('countdown', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.final-countdown.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
}
```

> Include the required bootstrap 3 CSS in the head of the page.

In the same function, add the following line:

```
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap_css', '//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

> Create a countdown timer using the html structure like this

See where you want to include it. If you want this on all the pages inside header, add this inside *header.php* in your theme folder.

> Add the following CSS snippet to your CSS file.

Just add the code inside your actual stylesheet.

> Initialize the countdown timer and set the start time, end time and current time in the javascript.

You could do this in your own js file. Add a *countdown.js* file in your js folder, and enqueue it like before:

```
wp_enqueue_script('countdown_script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/countdown.js', array('jquery'), '', true);
```

And in your *countdown.js* file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
        start: '1362139200',
        end: '1388461320',
        now: '1387461319'
    });
});
```

That way it will prevent any conflict.

Comment: really thank you very much , but i did all what you asked to me to do , but i got the error in the countdown.js , the error is :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ready' of undefined(anonymous function) @ countdown.js?ver=4.3.1:1

Comment: also , what about number 6 "  All the default options. " , what can i do

Comment: It's just an example of the options available. Use what you need.

Comment: And for your error, i made a mistake on countdown.js, see updated answer.

Comment: really i am sorry for disturbing you , but really i am newbie and need help and you the only one answered me , please forgive me for bothering you , but please help me , at least tell me why the countdown dose not working after i did all steps you asked from me !!! , thank you very very much

Comment: Hey np that's why we're here. I just checked and it seems the documentation is wrong on one point: you should add the "countdown" class to the countdown container. Try with this and let me know if it works. PS: nice website :)

Comment: i did , but no changes , still not working , now i can not do anything and i must wait for your answer again. thank you , you saw my website nice cause you are good and nice one

Comment: Allight now the plugin is initializing, but you have the following error: "Uncaught Can not find container in document with id canvas-seconds" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'draw' of undefined". The first one is because the the seconds container is identified by the id "canvas_seconds" and not "canvas-seconds". I think the html that has been provided on the documentation is not up-to-date compared to the last JS version. Change the 3 IDs (for hours and minutes too) and let's see if any other error occurs.